# Is it common to use the same name for the data type and value constructor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Looking at the following code:

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)
```

which is from the book Learn you a Haskell for Great Good, which accompanies this code example with the following text:

> Notice that when defining a point, we used the same name for the data type and the value constructor. This has no special meaning, although it's common to use the same name as the type if there's only one value constructor.

Now my assumption is that `data Point = ...` is the data type, and `... = Point Float...` is the value constructor.

My question is: **Is it common to use the same name for the data type and value constructor in Haskell?**

Comment: Yes, it is. However, we usually use `newtype` instead of `data`. For example, `State` is usually defined as follows: `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }`.

Comment: @AaditMShah That only works for single field constructors. Unless you want to unwrap a tuple everytime, you cannot use `newtype` for the mentioned `Point`.

Comment: I was pointed out to me once when I was explaining Haskell to someone that in some languages (e.g. Java), the constructor *always* has the same name as the type. So for someone coming to Haskell, it may be confusing to have different constructor names.

Comment: @user2297560 It's going to be more confusing that 1) constructors are mutually exclusive instead of calling one another; 2) they can't do any computation or argument validation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my limited experience: Yes. It makes sense, too. Why would you call `Point` differently here? It perfectly describes the data type and is also clear to use for pattern matching like this

```
myFunc :: Point -> Bool
myFunc (Point 0 0) = True
myFunc _ = False
```

It is unambiguous since you can only put the data type in the type signature of the function.

Comment: It does make a lot of sense. The one downside is that it's a bit confusing to beginners first learning the language—it's hard to follow that `Point` represents two different things in different contexts. This shouldn't affect how you write code in your projects or at work, but if you ever need to design an introductory curriculum around Haskell it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer, but a tip for people with the same question.

Syntax highlighting may help with the distinction between the two. For example a screenshot of some of the code mentioned before, from Visual Studio Code with [a Haskell Syntax Highlighting extension](https://github.com/JustusAdam/language-haskell) (with customized color coding):

[image: Haskell syntax highlighting]

Not everybody seems to agree with the accepted answer, by the way. See for example [this short post](https://int-index.github.io/posts/haskell-punning), as well as [this r/haskell discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/aliohu/termtype_punning_in_haskell_the_hidden_cost_of/) about it.

Comment: The "short post" link is broken.